# How to use assemble-middleware-i18n?

Tags: gruntjs, assemble, grunt-assemble

I am checking this plugin for localisation, but how should I use it after I have included it in my `gruntfile.js`?

it seemed there are some example usage [here](https://github.com/assemble/assemble-middleware-i18n/tree/master/test)

Answer (score 0):

There is still no documentation available, but there is a demo project by one of the developers

https://github.com/LaurentGoderre/i18n-demo